# Embed elements of a RecyclerView inside CardViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` that display the list of modifications per day for a document. Items are `TextView` with values like "Line 3 updated to ...", "Line 5 removed", etc. The `ViewHolder` handle 2 types of views :

- **Headers** : which are the days. These are simple `TextView` too that are in bold, larger, etc.
- **Logs**: that's what I was talking about : "Line 3 updated ...", etc.

What I would like is that each "day", with its corresponding logs are  embedded inside a `CardView`. But a document can have huge number of modifications per day (>100). So programmatically creating a layout with a  `CardView` as the root, calling 100 times addView() on it to add each logs and then passing this layout to the `RecyclerView` does not seems a good idea to me.

Is their any way to delimit between a "positionStart" and a "positionEnd" views that will be embedded inside a `CardView`? It seems to me that this isn't possible or by adding each `TextView` programmatically inside a `CardView` but it will then slow down the binding of the views and break the ViewHolder pattern. Am I right or is their a solution I didn't think about ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options to achieve this "grouped in a card" behavior.

1. (as mentioned) you create the layout yourself and put the whole thing into the recyclerview. This is probably the worst solution since it negates the idea of a recyclerview in the first place.
2. You just wrap each of your items in a `CardView` (and set the corner radius to `0dp`).
   On < 21 devices (I think) there will be some additional padding and every item will appear as its own card, but on higher API versions those cards will lie next to each other and just have some "seam" between them. The shadow on the corner is also a bit buggy, but this is probably the easiest and cheapest solution.

   Alternatively you can also create a custom view that fixes the errors mentioned above (margins between and shadow) and use your own to wrap the views. (I believe this is what the Inbox app does if I recall correctly, which also features lists in cards.)
3. You use an `ItemDecoration`. For this approach you need a kind of stable setup of your dataset, but if its just the headers and logs, you can draw a shadow above the header, draw borders to the left and right of every item, and draw a shadow beneath the last log. This will also require some setup, and if you introduce further view types you will also have to modify this code (it's highly dependent on your data set)

---

The *1.* method is probably the worst idea. It will work for small lists.

The *2.* method can work, but you either will have to create your own custom view or live with a "bugged" version on lower api levels.

The *3.* method is something I tried once for fun, and will work, but you will have some additional dependency between your data, your adapter, and your decoration. You can see an example of this [decoration here on GitHub](https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bleeding182/recyclerviewdecorations/CardViewDecoration.java). It just draws a shadow around all of the items.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I couldn't work on this due to project management.. But well, I tried your `ItemDecoration` and it's working well ! I just have a problem with the last item, it doesn't show the bottom shadow of the `CardView`. I assumed the issue is inside `onDrawOver`, I managed to detect when I'm on the last item (doesn't matter if this is a header or not) but I'm very bad with drawing in Android and I can't manage to set the bottom shadow at the right place, maybe you could help? Still Thank you for the great and detailed answer!